# Android add filter to user capture screenshot while in my app

Tags: android, screen-capture

Is there anyway to blur out or add filter to the screenshot that the users capture while inside my app? I know we can completely block the users from capturing the screenshot but I only want to blur it.

Answer (score 3):

> I know we can completely block the users from capturing the screenshot
>   but I only want to blur it.

AFAIK, there is no Broadcast triggered when a Screenshot is captured. Therefore, I am not sure if a possibility exists that you can detect that a Screenshot has been captured and then apply filters to, say blur it out.

**Source:** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#constants

Since an app can't detect a Screenshot has been taken, the best bet is to block that feature (*in your app only*) entirely. [**CommonsWare**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), on his blog has a method for blocking Screenshots from being caputured within your app. You will find details here: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/01/16/secure-against-screenshots.html

**An excerpt from that blog:**

To do that, use `FLAG_SECURE`:

```
public class FlagSecureTestActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                         LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

> Normally, when a user takes a screenshot, a Notification will be
>   raised to indicate success and provide access to the screenshot in the
>   Gallery app. With FLAG_SECURE in place, the Notification will be
>   “Couldn’t capture screenshot”.

Comment: Is it possible to block or edit the push notification "Couldn't capture screenshot"?